# I want a smalldatetime column to display dates in dd/mm/yy format. How can i do this

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want a smalldatetime column to display dates in dd/mm/yy format.

I used this statement to input values

```
Insert Into PriceTable(ICAOCode,IATACode,Departure,Price,RouteStatus)
Values  
('EKCH', 'NAX', '07/03/2015', '151', 'Ok');
```

The date above is the 7th of March 2015 but the date displays in Sql as 2015-07-03 00:00:00 which is the 3rd of July 2015.

Can I set the Departure column to display all dates as dd/mm/yy or will I have to convert each date entered individually.

Thank you for any help offered

Comment: which DMBS are you using ?

Comment: Sql server express 2014. I thought the tags would show that

Comment: If you're creating insert statement with dates, use always either YYYYMMDD format or convert / cast. Otherwise there's always a chance for an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to convert when selecting, with SQL-Server you could use the `Convert` function

```
SELECT Convert(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(yourDate,YourDateColumn,106),103)
```

Refer to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) for value 106 and 103.

Comment: Thanks Jean, I presume  by "convert when selecting" you mean convert when inserting. Please correct me if im wrong

Comment: Can converting the format to dd/mm/yy(for my own benefit) affect how the end user sees the date

Comment: @frustrationmultiplied only if you select it into the displayed value.

Comment: i dont understand. can you explain "select it into the displayed value". sorry for being a pain but im new to sql and im finding dealing with dates difficult

Comment: I mean that it will affect how the end users sees the date if the actual select convert it.